# Radio buttons do not check when clicking the label

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a group of 3 radio buttons in react semantic ui.

This works correctly. Problem is in UI bug, when I click on one of this radio buttons, buttons are not checked.

Screenshot of ui bug:

[image]

Is someone know why buttons are not checked?

Code of radio buttons:

```
  <Form>
    <Form.Field>
      <Radio
        label="New Claims"
        name="isTransferred"
        value={false}
        checked={isTransferred === false}
        onChange={this.handleFilterChanged}
      />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Radio
        label="Transferred Claims"
        name="isTransferred"
        value={false}
        checked={isTransferred === true}
        onChange={this.handleFilterChanged}
      />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Field>
      <Radio
        label="New Claims and Trasferred Claims"
        name="isTransferred"
        value={'all'}
        checked={isTransferred === 'all'}
        onChange={this.handleFilterChanged}
      />
    </Form.Field>
  </Form>
```

UPDATED:

Generated HTML taken from browser:

```
<div class="row">
<form class="ui form" style="padding-left: 3.3em;">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Assignments:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="isTransferred" readonly="" tabindex="0" value="false">
            <label>New Claims</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui checked radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="isTransferred" readonly="" tabindex="0" value="true">
            <label>Transferred Claims</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="isTransferred" readonly="" tabindex="0" value="all">
            <label>New Claims and Trasferred Claims</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: For Transferred Claims did you put any value there?

Comment: isTransferred is false by default.

Comment: You should set explicitely the value on your second radio for readability

Comment: Ok. What is the value of transferred claims when selected?

Comment: @JonathanHamel that is not problem, when you have just value in semantic and react that will automaticali be true.

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML for this?

Comment: I am using react dev tool, and when I select first button value is "value={false}" 
when select second button: value={true}, and third button value is "value={''all'}" 
From functional side this works fine. This is filter, and I get different expected result every time when I click on diff button. Problem is UI bug that checked missed.

Comment: @MrLister I update the post with generated html.

Comment: Could you share the whole component? It seems to a "controlled" component issue

Comment: @MarkJames In generated html I don't see `for` attribute in label and there is no `id` in input tag.

Comment: The generated code if put on a jsfiddle works fine. Is something happening on the click event handler? Is the Radio Component a custom component? If it is custom made by you is there no css rule for changing the button style when it is selected?

Comment: I guess it is semantic-ui react components. The issue is with js code

Comment: It seems to me like the problem is in `handleFilterChanged`. It should look something like `handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })`. Have a look at this working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ry9lwp5joq?module=/example.js

Comment: Atlease, share `handleFilterChanged` listener

Comment: @MoorthyG maybe you can make answer for this solution if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The label must have the "for" attribute for an input element to react to a click on its label.

The value of the "for" attribute must be an "id" of an input element.

I believe it should work if you add "id" property to the Radio element.

More information can be found here: [HTML  element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes)

Comment: +1 : but would add, that the label could work without the `for` attribute, IF it wraps the input element. `<label><input type="checkbox"...>description</label>`

Comment: indeed, it worked without `for`: `<Radio
                label="user-id"
                id="user-id"
                name="radioGroup"
                value="user-id"
                checked={value1 === 'user-id'}
                onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, 1)}
              />`

Comment: Might also want to note that you have unique Id and `for` for each element. Made a silly mistake of having same Id and hence same `for` for multiple elements and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  `checked = true`  instead of `checked={isTransferred === false}` and also try to insert the value of the `label` inside `value`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by bellow modification.

```
<Form.Radio
label="New Claims"
id="New Claims"
key="New Claims"
name="assignments"
value={isTransferred}
checked={isTransferred === true}
onChange={this.handleFilterChanged}
/>
```